# An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the PutSubscriptionFilter operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Trying to put cloud watch logs into kineses firehose.

Followed below:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#FirehoseExample

Got this error

An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the PutSubscriptionFilter operation: Could not deliver test message to specified Firehose stream. Check if t
e given Firehose stream is in ACTIVE state.

aws logs put-subscription-filter --log-group-name "xxxx" --filter-name "xxx" --filter-pattern "{$.httpMethod = GET}" --destination-arn "arn:aws:firehose:us-east-1:12345567:deliverystream/xxxxx" --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::12344566:role/xxxxx"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely problem that causes this error is a permissions issue. i.e. something wrong in the definition of the IAM role you passed to `--role-arn`. You may want to double check that the role and its permissions were set up properly as described in the doc.

Answer (score 8):

You need to update the trust policy of your IAM role so that it gives permissions to the `logs.amazonaws.com` service principal to assume it, otherwise CloudWatch Logs won't be able to assume your role to publish events to your Kinesis stream.  (Obviously you also need to double-check the permissions on your role to make sure it has permissions to read from your Log Group and write to your Kinesis Stream.)

It would be nice if they added this to the error message to help point people in the right direction...

Answer (score 2):

I was getting a similar error when subscribing to a cloudwatch loggroup and publishing to a Kinesis stream. Cdk was not defining a dependency needed for the SubscriptionFilter to be created after the Policy that would allow the filtered events to be published in Kinesis. This is reported in this github cdk issue:

https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/21827

I ended up using the workaround implemented by github user AlexStasko: https://github.com/AlexStasko/aws-subscription-filter-issue/blob/main/lib/app-stack.ts

Answer (score 0):

If your Firehose is active status and you can send log stream then the remaining issue is only policy.

I got the similar issue when follow the tutorial. The one confused here is Kinesis part and Firehose part, we may mixed up together. You need to recheck your: ~/PermissionsForCWL.json, with details part of:

```
....
"Action":["firehose:*"], *// You could confused with kinesis:* like me*
"Resource":["arn:aws:firehose:region:123456789012:*"]
....
```

Answer (score 0):

When I did the tutorial you mentioned, it was defaulting to a different region so I had to pass `--region` with my region. It wasn't until I did the entire steps with the correct region that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me I think this issue was occurring due to the time it takes for the IAM data plane to settle after new roles are created via regional IAM endpoints for regions that are geographically far away from us-east-1.

I have a custom Lambda CF resource that auto-subscribes all existing and future log groups to a Firehose via a subscription filter. The IAM role gets deployed for CW Logs then very quickly the Lambda function tries to subscribe the log groups. And on occasion this error would happen.

I added a time.sleep(30) to my code (this code only runs once a stack creation so it's not going to hurt anything to wait 30 seconds).