# AWS Put Subscription Filter for Kinesis Firehose using Cloudformation - Check if the given Firehose stream is in ACTIVE state

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Following this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#FirehoseExample) and creating a Kinesis Firehose Stream.

I have followed the guide and when I get to creating a subscription filter (step 12), I encounter this error when trying to send to S3:

An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the PutSubscriptionFilter operation: Could not deliver test message to specified Firehose stream. Check if the given Firehose stream is in ACTIVE state.

I can confirm that the stream is active and I can send test data via the console and it arrives in S3 as expected.

This is the command I am running (changed my account id):

```
aws logs put-subscription-filter --log-group-name "myLogGroup" --filter-name "Destination" --filter-pattern "{$.userIdentity.type = Root}" --destination-arn "arn:aws:firehose:ap-southeast-1:1234567890:deliverystream/my-delivery-stream" --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/CWLtoKinesisFirehoseRole"
```

I have checked the trusted entities and the role has priviliges to logs and firehose. Any ideas?

Comment: There's was similar question on Stack Overflow some time ago that might help you resolve the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53828913/an-error-occurred-invalidparameterexception-when-calling-the-putsubscriptionfi

Comment: Can you show the role for CW-logs that you use?

Comment: @DennisTraub I saw that already and tried the steps listed there but it didn't solve my issue.

Comment: @Marcin here is the role for CW-Logs

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "firehose:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:firehose:ap-southeast-1:12345:deliverystream/Stream",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::12345:role/Stack57-CWLtoKinesisFirehoseRole-1PAUVCYZPRYWL",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but I found I needed to add the `AmazonKinesisFirehoseFullAccess` permission to my IAM role.

Answer (score 2):

I also struggle with this for a long time, for me it was those 2 gothca's:

step 4 in the guide:
make sure to change to bucket name to you bucket:

[image]

step 8 !!!:

make sure to put your account ID it is not highlighted:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you already know how to configure logs subscription filter so not adding steps in my answer

1. Go to firehose and check logs is your firehose has access to execute lambda ,if not please add required role.
2. Now start dummy data stream using firehose test and see is your data is moving till lambda or S3.
3. check cloud trail and cloud watch logs and see if found any error .
4. Open your IAM role and check all required role added to your role , now click trust relationship add- "logs group ","IAM" and component name in my case its "Ec2"

Hope this will helpful to resolve your issue.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#FirehoseExample

Answer (score 0):

This is a permission issue between Cloudwatch Logs and the Firehose stream. Likely your role & policy are wrong.

I followed [this doc](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cloudwatch-logs-stream-to-kinesis) replacing `kinesis` with `firehose` where needed, ending up with:

- this IAM policy:

  ```
  {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [{
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": "firehose:PutRecord",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:firehose:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:deliverystream/STREAM_NAME"
      }]
  }
  ```
- an IAM role which:

  - includes the policy created above
  - has the following trust relationship:

    ```
     {
         "Version": "2012-10-17",
         "Statement": [{
             "Effect": "Allow",
             "Principal": {
                 "Service": "logs.REGION.amazonaws.com"
             },
             "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
             "Condition": {
                 "StringLike": {
                     "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:logs:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:*"
                 }
             }
         }]
     }
    ```
- choosing that IAM role when creating the log group destination

Don't forget to replace `REGION`, `ACCOUNT_ID`, `STREAM_NAME`.